# October CMS belongsToMany/hasMany relation to self

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I followed the excellent answer given here: [October CMS relation to self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52961104/october-cms-relation-to-self)

But was left with one problem; it's a one-way relation. In my case I have a "domain" which can have many domains. However, although "domain A" is linked to "domain B" and "domain C", this wasn't the other way around. When editing "Domain B" it wasn't linked to "Domain A" when using the method given by Hardik.

Documentation states:

> "To define the inverse of a many-to-many relationship, you simply
>   place another $belongsToMany property on your related model."

, but this is impossible since the model can only have one `$belongsToMany` property?

So how do I realize the inverse in a relation to itself?

Comment: hmm i guess 2 way self relation on same level seems little complex, as you can see practically its like recurion. A is belogs to B and nor B blongs to A -> and now A blongs to B it becomes recursive i guess. may be need different approach ?

Comment: sorry some typos in comments was in hurry : `A is belogs to B and now B blongs to A -> and now A blongs to B it becomes recursive i guess`, but still i can check if it can be possible for 1 level :)

Comment: It shouldn't be recursive if it's a one time check; Link A to B -> also link B to A.

Answer (score 1):

So as I have done a couple self referencing relationships I have found a many-to-many relationship function uses the primary model is the `key` and the joining model is the `otherKey`. This is always how the interpreter works. Here examples and solutions I have found.

**Here is a belongsToMany relationship**

```
public $belongsToMany = [
    'relation' => [
        'Author\Plugin\Models\Datas', 
        'table' => 'author_plugin_datapivot', 
        'key' => 'relation_one', 
        'otherKey' => 'relation_two'
    ]
];
```

To get the two way many to many relationship working the pivot table needs to look like this. relation_one contains `record.id` | relation_two contains `relation.id` and the recursive `relation.id` | `record.id`.

[image]

**Solution 1 - Create an inverseRelation** - Problem with this is now you have to check the model for a `relation` and an `inverseRelation`.

```
public $belongsToMany = [
    'relation' => [
        'Author\Plugin\Models\Datas', 
        'table' => 'author_plugin_datapivot', 
        'key' => 'relation_one', 
        'otherKey' => 'relation_two'
    ],
    'inverseRelation' => [
        'Author\Plugin\Models\Datas', 
        'table' => 'author_plugin_datapivot', 
        'key' => 'relation_two', 
        'otherKey' => 'relation_one'
    ]
];
```

**Solution 2 - Create a function afterSave -- I couldn't get this to work how I wanted** - I believe this is possible, my theory was to access the model's relations and then iterate through them to attach this record. However I think attaching the relation is done after the model is saved so you don't have access to the relations yet. There are probably ways to use this method still like maybe a temporary field that holds the id's of the records you want to save. I am not going to try it though.

```
public function afterSave()
{
    $relations = $this->relations;
    dd($this);
    foreach ($relations as $relation) {
        $relation->relations()->attach($this);
    }
}
```

**Solution 3 - Create a component/class function** - I chose this because I hardly use the backend to edit model data. I created a class function that handles attaching the relations recursively. Key things to note that I found it faster to remove all attached relations (`detach()`) then checking to see if I am attaching a duplicate. This is important because you will get an error for attaching duplicates. Also note that using a class function I can look for unique properties where I wouldn't want to use a many-to-many relationship.

```
public function attachMany($field, $record, $relation)
{
    if ($record->relations->first()) {
        foreach ($record->relations as $relation) {
            $relation->relations()->detach($record);
            $record->relations()->detach($relation);
        }
    }
    if ($field->unique) {
        $relationRecord->relation_bto()->add($record);
    } else {
        $relationRecord->relations()->attach($record);
        $record->relations()->attach($relationRecord);
    }
}
```

PS I would be curious to know if anyone has found the most optimal way to do this. These are the solutions I have found and so far I have gotten by.

Comment: How would I go about implementing Solution 3? Is it something put in the model to be called after save or? I'm not quite sure where to put it and how to use it.

Comment: [Create a component/class function](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components) - This doesn't work directly with the backend end plugin controllers though. You would have to have [an event](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/events) that fires `afterSave()`.